# how to redirect from one page to another in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

I work on joomla in which I have one menu to which I added a php page. In the php page I have a button. When the button is clicked, I want to redirect the user to another php page.

Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code on the page where you want the php redirect button to appear.

```
<?php

   echo '<input name="redirectbutton" type="button" onClick="location.href=\'main.php\'" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; font-size: 36px; font-weight:bold; font-style: italic;" value="Done">';

?>
```

Remember to change `href=\'main.php\` to the location you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<a href="http://...">text</a>` tag :)